# Trello list scraper that extracts all numbers from boards and logs the sum

Tags: python

I wrote a script that pulls all the cards in my food expenses list that are separated by months. I then extract all the numbers and log the sum to a file. Later I plan on graphing my monthly expenses and the names.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from trollop import TrelloConnection
import logging 
# Lots of issues with Python3. Lots of unicode, string errors, Just switched to 
# py2. should try to use dicts for {name: cost} and to  practice using dicts 

# TODO: Data Visualization, Error/exception handling, appending to log for running total
# TODO: clean up code, get feedback on reddit, maybe use args for spec params
# TODO: set up cron job to run every month

api_key = '####' # TRELLO_API_KEY
token = '####'
# idBoard': '577b17583e5d17ee55b20e44',
# idList': '577b17583e5d17ee55b20e45',
# Set up basic logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO, filename='trello_expenses.log', filemode='w')

# Establish connection
conn = TrelloConnection(api_key, token)
months = ['January', 'February', 'July', 'August', \
          'September','October','November', 'December']
# Get expenses board via ID

logging.info("Iterating through boards...")

# for board in conn.me.boards:
#     # logging.info("id: {}".format(each._id))
#     # print u"board name: {0}, board id {1}" . format( board.name, board._id )  
#     logging.info (u"board name: {0}, board id {1}".\
#                     format( board.name, board._id ))  

# for each_card in conn.me.boards[2].cards:
#     print u"{0},{1},{2}".format(each_card._id, each_card.url,each_card.desc)  

def main():
    total = 0.0
    costs = list()
    names = list()

    # get first index i.e the list im currently working on
    board = conn.get_board('BE89pW61')
    board_lists = board.lists
    current = board_lists[0]
    # Get all lists  names and ids in board
    for entry in board_lists:

        if 'august' in entry.name.lower():
            # print u'List name: {0} list id: {1}'.format (entry.name, entry._id)

            for cards in entry.cards:
                name, cost =  cards.name.split('-')
                costs.append(float (cost) )
                # print cards.name
            # print costs
    total = sum (costs)
    print 'total is {}'.format( total )


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `board_lists` is a useless variable and since it looks very similar to `board.lists`, it is a potential source of confusion later. Just use `board.lists` unless you need to do something special to a copy of `board.lists` that you don't want to do to `board.lists` itself. In your code as is, you are just inspecting the contents, so it should be OK.

Comment: `current` appears unused. It looks like you have commented out lines for debugging so it is a little uncertain what "correct" output for your code should be

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Hope you get some nice answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good to see that you are using the `if __name__=='__main__':` guard. However, I think you are doing a bit too much in your `main` and I would make a `get_total_month` function like this:

```
...
def get_total_month(month, board_lists):
    costs = 0
    month = month.lower()
    for entry in board_lists:
        if month in entry.name.lower():
            for card in entry.cards:
                costs += float(card.name.split('-')[1])
    return costs


def main():
    board = conn.get_board('BE89pW61')
    total = get_total_month('august', board.lists)
    print 'total is {}'.format(total)
```

This way it will be easier to incorporate for example something like:

```
totals_per month = [get_total_month(month, boards.lists) for month in months]
```

which is then easy to plot e.g. with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

totals = [get_total_month(month, boards.lists) for month in months]
months = range(len(months))

plt.plot(months, totals)
plt.show()
```

Adding the actual names of the month (and maybe also their year) is a bit more involved, but you can have a look at the examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html).

Regarding whitespace, try to stick to one convention, preferentially the one set by pythons offical style-guie, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This means in particular not writing `sum (total)` or `float( entry )`, but `sum(total)` and `float(entry)`.

Comment: I see you got rid of my costs list(). I'm assuming that just having costs as a float instead of a list I append to, makes the code more compact and faster?

Comment: Should I now `zip` my months and totals ?

Comment: @user3577138 Yes, `int` addition is faster than `list.append` and more memory efficient if you don't need the individual results. For the `zip`, do you mean for plotting?

Answer (score 1):

Can you take a look at this line:

> ```
> logging.info("Iterating through boards...")
> ```

It will be executed even if you import this file. Maybe you should move it (and the related code) to the main section?